# django multiple signup forms

Tags: python, django

I want to have in my project 3 applications: 
Home, User, Company
Home is the main app where all users can go from page to page, and on this home app now I have buttons Login and Sign Up. 
Now it's made like this:

Home/forms.py

```
    class LoginForm(forms.Form):
        username = forms.CharField(
            widget=forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'
                }))
        password = forms.CharField(
            widget=forms.PasswordInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'
                }))

        def clean_username(self):
            username = self.cleaned_data['username']
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(username=username)
                return username
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Incorrect login")

        def clean_password(self):
            if self.cleaned_data['username']:
                username = self.cleaned_data['username']
                password = self.cleaned_data['password']
                user = User.objects.get(username=username)
                if user.check_password(password):
                    return password
                raise forms.ValidationError("Incorrect password")
            raise forms.ValidationError("Incorrect login")

class RegisterUserForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'
                }))
    email = forms.EmailField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'
                }))
    password1 = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'
                }))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'
                }))

class RegisterCompanyForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'
                }))

    password1 = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'
                }))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'
                }))
    nip = forms.CharField(
        widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={
            'class': 'form-control'
        }))
```

In views I have register_user_page and register_company_page with their own templates and forms. 
How can I now sign up these two types of users? Is it even correct to handle that in forms?
And also if User will log in he needs to be redirect to app User, and Company redirect to Company app.

Comment: What do mean by saying _application_?

Comment: I mean something like module to separate their functionalities. I'm new to django and I thought it will be good idea to separate it but maybe I was wrong